# Возможно ли в Unity Input Manager добавить UI Button?

Tags: unity3d, ui

Есть ли какая-то возможность в Unity добавить события получаемые из UI (например клик с кнопки) в стандартный Input Manager?

Comment: Можно поподробней пожалуйста, не совсем понятно, что имеется в виду?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного поковырявшись, я понял что разработчики Unity настоятельно рекомендуют всем переходить на новую Input System, которая доступна в версии 1.0.1 начиная с версии Unity 2019.1. Устанавливается через Package Manager:

[image: Input System]

Официальная документация находится [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/index.html).

Новая система гораздо более гибкая, в том числе есть решение по моему вопросу. На кнопку (или другой элемент UI) вешается компонент, в котором указывается какую клавишу она должна дублировать:

[image: On-Screen Button]

Далее при нажатии на эту наэкранную кнопку будет отрабатываться логика, которую вы прописали для этой клавиши, ничего дополнительного городить не нужно.

Решил поделиться, возможно кому-то будет полезно.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, вы не можете сами добавлять события в стандартный **Input Manager**.

Вы можете написать **wrapper** к стандартному **Input Manager** который бы возвращал что-то что вам надо. (и этому **wrapper** ни кто не мешает внутри использовать `Input.GetAxis`) или поискать **asset** который уже умеет так делать.

Хотя во многих ситуациях такие выкрутасы не нужны, вполне будет достаточно чего-то вроде:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Button = UnityEngine.UIElements.Button;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Button rightButton;
    private Direction direction = Direction.Undefined; //поле, кот. влияет на общий функционал

    private void Start()
    {
        rightButton.clicked += () => { direction = Direction.Right;}; // изменение влияющей переменной на основе UI события
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            direction = Direction.Right; // изменение влияющей переменной на основе InputManager
        }

        Move();  // вызов метода с общим функционалом
    }

    private void Move() // метод с общим функционалом
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case Direction.Up:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case Direction.Down:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case Direction.Left:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case Direction.Right:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case Direction.Undefined:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

public enum Direction
{
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right,
    Undefined
}
```